# How to write a batch file to install an application package on a network which is having 500+users?

Tags: installation, batch-file

I am having an application package which will be useful in prodution environment. I need to install by running a batch file without disturbing the users.

Comment: What kind of package do you want to install, on what environment? Your question needs to be way more specific then this.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is done by creating a "quiet" installer, which installs your app without any queries to the user or progress meters, and then distributing the installer using Microsoft SMS or other desktop management tool your organization already uses (if it's 500+ users, you must be using some tool...)

Answer (score 0):

You might get a better response by asking this on the Sysadmin sister site: http://serverfault.com.